# How to make right color compression for internet images?

Tags: website-design, color, compression

How to make right color/image compression for internet images?
I adjust images in the Adobe Lightroom, then I export them to the Adobe Photoshop (there are already some changes - pictures looks more grainy then in the Lightroom). And after that, when I upload them to the internet, colors looks completely different. I tried to save it in JPG, PNG, PNG for web, but everything looks wih the same problem in the end

Comment: Depending on the site you upload them to, some sites might apply filters to your image to decrease its filesize.

Comment: If they look worse *after* uploading to the Internet then wherever or whatever you are uploading the images too is adding its own compression to your images.

Comment: Hi Celkem, sorry to hear you're having trouble. As it stands, your question is a guessing game for us. Without knowing specifically how the image is being changed upon upload or what server you're uploading to, it's near impossible to definitively answer this.

Answer (score 1):

In general scenario, every browser render you image in sRGB color space; you can check this out to be sure: [Gérer les couleurs avec Photoshop](http://www.color-management-guide.com/web-browser-color-management.html)
The trick for showing the right color *(let's say, you have a specific red that you want to see the same in browser)* is to assign you image a color profile and save the image with embeded color profile.
So: you have an image opened in Photoshop. You can assign profile in "Edit > Assign Profile" and choose sRGB *(or even with Convert to Profile - the difference is that this method converts every color to that profile and MAY distort them a bit, even is the right way)*, then, when you save it, make sure you have the "Embed Color Profile" checked - check this out: [Color Settings in Adobe Photoshop](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1315593&seqNum=6)